# Number validation - reference to another attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I need a validation to check whether an attribute is less or equal than another (virtual) attribute of the same record. How can I do that?

Sample code (not working - NoMethodError):

```
attr_reader :virt
attr_accessible :virt

validates :my_attr, :numericality => {:only_integer => true, :less_or_equal => self.virt}
```

(please be gentle and explicit, I'm a RoR newb :])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since those validation lines are going to be executed when the class definition is first encountered, `self.virt` doesn't exist.

You can usually pass in a lambda/proc instead that will be `call`ed at validation time from the scope of the object:

```
validates :my_attr, :numericality => { :less_or_equal => lambda { virt } }
```

This still isn't that great, though. A better route would be to just define your own validation method:

```
validate :my_attr_is_within_range

def my_attr_is_within_range
  my_attr <= virtual_attribute
end
```

This is much cleaner and more explicit. Note that you don't need to use `self` here since there is no ambiguity (if you were setting you would need the `self`).